# php://input only works under root directory

Tags: php

I have a site that will read XML post with the php://input under root directory but will not under a sub directory.

I can tell by the empty request xml file it generates in the sub directory.

```
 <?php

    $post       = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));


    $timeStamp  = date("Y-m-d") . "T" . date( "H:i:sP" );
    $xmlName    = "setupRequest" . $timeStamp . ".xml";
    $FileHandle = fopen( "xml/" . $xmlName, 'w' ) or die( "can't open file" ); 
    fwrite( $FileHandle, $post ); 
    fclose( $FileHandle );
    ?>
```

It has been tested on two different URLs one pointed at the root and the other pointed at the sub directory.   We always get blank 'setupRequest' file from the sub directory.

What could be an issue with this code?

Here is .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.reallighting.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http\:\/\/reallighting\.com\/$1 [R=301,L]
# Start WPFC Exclude
# End WPFC Exclude
# Start_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in_[^\=]+\=AndyAdmin|ETCAdmin|RealAdmin
# End_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^reallighting.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(facebookexternalhit|WhatsApp|Mediatoolkitbot)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/){2}$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !comment_author_
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wp_woocommerce_session
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !safirmobilswitcher=mobil
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f [or]
RewriteCond /homepages/37/d276009229/htdocs/WP/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "index\.(html|htm)$">
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Mon, 29 Oct 1923 20:30:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END WpFastestCache

# BEGIN WPSuperCache
# END WPSuperCache

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: The user that is running as PHP doesn't have the necessary permissions to read the file. Check out this link for more info: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35711/giving-php-permission-to-write-to-files-and-folders

Comment: can you show the (relevant) folder structure? How do you call that script? What Method (Post/Put)?

Comment: @BillH then there would be _no_ file at all, wouldn't it?

Comment: Just to clarify, you drop this file into your web root and it works but when you drop it into a sub-directory it doesn't work?

Comment: @BillH `php://input` isn't a file, there's no permission required to read it. What file are you talking about?

Comment: What happens if you just do `echo strlen($post);` instead of trying to write it to a file?

Comment: BTW, the sequence `fopen/fwrite/fclose` can be simplified to `file_put_contents($filename, $post);`

Comment: @Barmar I meant write but SO wouldn't let me edit the comment for 5 mins. When I read the original question I understood it as the input wasn't writing to the subdirectory.

Comment: @Barmar I know that a connection is being made to the subdirectory from an existing log file that is in the same directory where the request file is supposed to be written to from xml. That log file gets written to saying that a connection has been made.  But the incoming xml is not appearing in the request file.

Comment: That's not what I asked. If you log `strlen($post)`, does it show the expected length? I'm trying to pin down whether the problem is with reading the input or writing to the file.

Comment: @Barmar  The string length is 0.  I did see on the this directory that there is a 705 permissions on the xml directory its trying to write to. On the working xml directory it is 777

Comment: If the directory is owned by the webserver userid, only the first digit of the permissions is relevant.

Comment: Is there a `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory? Maybe it has some setting that's affecting the PHP input.

Comment: There is a .htaccess file in the subdirectory.  I'll try to find out if there is some setting there.